# Get all results of 1 year ago and older datetime field

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check if an membership of an user is created 1 year ago or longer.
I have this now:

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

But i get results of 17-03-2021 in the list, when that is not an year ago.
I want to get all results from the Users when created account one year ago
or longer than.

How i can do that? I googled but i cant find an solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are checking if the `date` is **larger** than `NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR`. I think it should be `<` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

Where date smaller then one year ago, you had greater then.